# Can I use SVG-animation in Cocos2d-JS?

Tags: animation, svg, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

Is it possible to use SVG-animation in cocos2d-js? If Yes, how can I do this? I would like to use it in my project. If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think that cocos2d-js supports svg animation. However there are several tools, provided by cocos2d-js which allow you to animate your Sprites. This includes things like moving, scaling and rotating. Just check the reference for that.
If you want to have more advanced animation you should have a look at SpriteSheet-animations, which allows you to use several pictures and put them together as an animation. Have a look at this documentation: http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/parkour-game-with-javascript-v3.0/chapter5/en/index.html 
If you do not want to buy TexturePacker, you can also use my own fork of an open source alternative: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/spritesheetcreator-open-source-alternative-to-texturepacker/27955 
Just let me know if you have any further questions.